# Airflow DAG: How to insert data into a table using Python operator, not BigQuery operator?

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-storage, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to insert some data into a table using a simple Python operator, not the BigQuery operator, but I am unsure how to implement this. I am trying to implement this in the form of an Airflow DAG.

I have written a simple DAG, and I have managed to use the following to insert the data from a GCS Bucket to BigQuery, but I am wanting to do this using a Python operator instead, not BigQuery:

```
load_csv = gcs_to_bq.GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq_example',
    bucket='cloud-samples-data',
    source_objects=['bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv'],
    destination_project_dataset_table='airflow_test.gcs_to_bq_table',
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'post_abbr', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    ],
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    dag=dag)
```

I am wanting to achieve the above using a simple Python operator instead of BigQuery.

BQ to GCS:
BigQuery to GCS:

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
project = "bigquery-public-data"
dataset_id = "samples"
table_id = "shakespeare"

destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "shakespeare.csv")
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location="US",
)  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

print(
    "Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri)
)
```

Comment: Why do you wano using a `PythonOperator` instead of `GCSToBigQueryOperator` ?

Comment: I am wanting to accomplish the same task using the ```PythonOperator```. I just need help to write the code I have, but using the ```PythonOperator``` instead. This is just to expand my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BigQuery` `Python` [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#python) in a `PythonOperator` to insert `GCS` files to `BigQuery`, example :

```py
PythonOperator(
    task_id="gcs_to_bq",
    op_kwargs={
      'dataset': 'dataset',
      'table': 'table'
    },
    python_callable=load_gcs_files_to_bq
)

def load_gcs_files_to_bq(dataset, table):
   from google.cloud import bigquery

   # Construct a BigQuery client object.
   client = bigquery.Client()

   # TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
   table_id = f"your-project.{dataset}.{table}"

   job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
             bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
             bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
        ],
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    )
    
    uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.

    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

    destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide me with a solution for my answer. I assume I can incorporate this into my Airflow DAG, right?

Comment: You're welcome, you have to adapt this code a little bit, for example set your `projectId`, `dataset` and `table`. Check also the `GCS` uri and set your path. The `BigQuery` schema seems to be OK.

Comment: Thanks very much. Yeah, I know I have to change a few things, but I can definitely put this into my DAG.

Comment: You're welcome :), yes you can. Don't hesitate to add an upvote to increase the visibility of my answer and help others.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough rep to upvote.

Comment: Also, do I need to do something similar if I want to extract a table from BigQuery to GCS?

Comment: You can use the built in operator to do that or use the same technique as I shown in my answer.

Comment: Ok, but do I need to define a function to use the following code? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-extract-table#bigquery_extract_table-python

Comment: Yes !! the principle is the same and you can use this function in a `PythonOperator`. Please it's better to avoid extended discussions in comments :), if you will be blocked, you can create a new and separated Stackoverflow topic.